# Creating text index in pymongo

Tags: regex, mongodb, pymongo, full-text-indexing

I have a database of English words stored in the field 'h'. I've just found out about text indexes and I wanna create one on this field to speed up searching by regex, but somehow, I just can't get the syntax right. I'm using pymongo 2.7.1 and python 3.4.

```
 from pymongo import MongoClient
 from pymongo import ASCENDING
 from pymongo import DESCENDING
 from pymongo import TEXT
 #...
 collection.create_index('h', TEXT)
```

And I'm getting the following error:

```
in create_index
raise TypeError("cache_for must be an integer or float.")
TypeError: cache_for must be an integer or float.
```

Note that ASCENDING and DESCENDING work. Also I'd like to set the default language as English.

Comment: I have no idea but seems that TEXT is not supported for your create_index, and it neeeds an integer or float instead.

Comment: Well, ascending and descending are ints, so I'd expect text to be too. I've also tried with ensure_index and it still doesn't work.

Comment: I think you should confirm that TEXT is an integer or float.

Comment: Apparently it's not. It's the string 'text'.

Comment: I was about to suggest 'text'...

Comment: @thehousedude Great! you found the issue. I can post the answer if you want, or you can do it in order to close this question.

Comment: Apparently this seems to work `collection.create_index([('h', TEXT)], cache_for=300, default_language='english')` but I'm not posting it yet, cause mongod says `warning: cannot find special index [text]`. It probably needs a name. I'll come back to you.

Answer (score 16):

Sending it as an array worked.

`collection.create_index([('h', TEXT)], default_language='english')`

I've also used collection.getIndexes() to check it:

```
    {
    "key" : {
        "h" : "text"
    },
    "ns" : "a.a",
    "name" : "h_text"
}
```